# xcode can't add additional project into workspace

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

When adding a new project into workspace it is not possible to expand it, it is not compilable, and it's related files are not accessible, it seems as if xcode treat it as a resource file ( although it is able to resolve the proper icon ).

This is the way I add the proj

1. xcode->File->Add Files to "%ProjName%"
2. Select the project file

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: actualy, what you trying to do? you want to create a new xcode project? or need to add a new file?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The problem was that I had the project being added opened in another IDE, having that other IDE closed resolved the problem

Comment: It's silly that there isn't any kind of notification for this issue.  Just a very non-instrusive "project open in another application" or some such would be VERY helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your project & select new project give name which adds new project in your workspace. See image for reference.

[image: see here].

You can also add new project by drag & drop.